# Is it safe to use multiple startTransaction and commitTransaction with just one last endTransaction in iBatis?

Tags: java, transactions, ibatis

I wrote a program to insert bulk data. To speed up, I committed transaction in the middle of process.
Is it safe to call startTransaction and commitTransaction many times and call endTransaction just once?

```
try {
  sqlMap.startTransaction();
  // Do some work.      
  sqlMap.commitTransaction();

  sqlMap.startTransaction();
  // Do some work. 
  sqlMap.commitTransaction();

  sqlMap.startTransaction();
  // Do some work. 
  sqlMap.commitTransaction();
} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  throw new MyException();
} finally {
  try {
    sqlMap.endTransaction();
  }
  catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new MyException();
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need a transaction for every insert you do?  You are not going to speed up anything with a transaction on every insert. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288256/fastest-way-for-doing-inserts-using-ibatis .

Also for me your try catch block looks weird and may be misleading : one or many transactions may not be executed if something went wrong (it will stop on the first failed transaction).

Comment: I inserted 10000 records for each transaction and it was faster then inserting records without transaction. The transaction here is just for speed up not for actual transaction. Therefore, it is fine that the following code is not executed when something went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iBatis, startTransaction, commitTransaction, endTransaction should be called one time in order as stated. If you call startTransaction and commitTransaction many times without calling endTransaction, you will run out of db connection and get errors.